# Laravel create controller method to update 1 column from 1 row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am making a website for a dog shelter, and I want to make a button which would mark the dog as adopted. In other words, I am trying to update 1 column from 1 row. It will always be set from false to true.

I have tried making my own method in my existing controller, adding a route and creating a form, but I get errors that some other fields are also required, which are the same required fields when I would create a new dog (name, sex, DoB etc).

Code of the method in my controller:

```
public function markAsAdopted(Request $request, $id){
    $pet = Pet::table('pets')->where('id', $id)->update(['is_adopted' => true]);

    return redirect("/pets/$pet->id")->with('success', 'Successfully marked as adopted');
}
```

Code of the route:

```
Route::patch('/pets/{id}', 'PetsController@markAsAdopted');
```

Code of the form:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['PetsController@markAsAdopted', $pet->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right ml-1 mr-1']) !!}
    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PATCH')}}
    {{Form::submit('Mark as adopted', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The form is on the page /pets/{id}
I have created all the other routes in this controller with the --resource flag when creating the controller, so the skeleton of CRUD was there.

Did I miss something? OR is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Paste here the errors you're getting.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký they arent errors which break the app, just that some fields are missing. here is a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/giVWCAi.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is routing the `markAsAdopted` call to your `update()` (or possibly `create()` depending on how you have your Routes set) instead of the `markAsAdopted()` method.  This is, in turn, calling your PetsRequest class (or whatever you've called your verification class).

It is most likely coming in as a POST and possibly ignoring the PATCH method, thus routed to `update()`.  You can do a couple of things - move the patch method higher in Routes file and test by changing to POST.  If this works, you know this is the problem.  This is just a test - you will break the other pets POST coming in below it in the Routes file, so remember to change it back :)

I typically skip the PATCH thing altogether though, as I've run into similar issues.  I normally just make a POST route with a special name (e.g. `Route::post('/petsMarkAsAdopted/{id}', 'PetsController@markAsAdopted');`) and open the form with the url to that special route.

If you really want to keep the PATCH, do the higher placement test above, and you can use blade to set the method after you open your form, like so:

```
@method('PATCH')
```

**Edit:**  As noted in the comments, the above fixes the routing, but there is a different problem in your controller method now that we can access it.  Take out the `table()`, and just call the model to get the pet your need.  I've separated out the call for clarity:

```
$pet = Pet::where('id', $id)->first();
$pet->update(['is_adopted' => true]);
```

Comment: it still gives the same query errors if i place the method at the top, but if I am able to do it your way I don't mind it. I will try now, thank you

Comment: Yep, sounds like it is routing to the wrong place.  Try with the POST and the unique route using URL (not action) in the form open - should work fine into the markAsAdopted method which has no PetsRequest validation.

Comment: Could you push me in the right direction? I have created the route you told me, but I am not sure what I should do with the form

Comment: Sure: easiest to name the route: **Route::post('/petsMarkAsAdopted/{id}', 'PetsController@markAsAdopted')->name('adopted.update')**   Then open the form to the named route:  **{!! Form::model($pet, array('route' => array('adopted.update', $pet->id), 'method'=>'POST'))!!}**  This uses binding - you can do it without using URL() as well, but this should get you close.  Make sure this is not inside the normal update form for the whole pet - that would also cause the wrong routing.

Comment: it returns this error: **Call to undefined method App\Pet::table()**

Comment: Good!  That means we've fixed the routing.  You have a different problem in your method, which I will edit into my answer.

Comment: it worked!!!! thank you so so much, this really means a lot! 
also to add, if anyone has this problem, I had to **add a property in the model**:
protected $fillable = ['is_adopted'];